# Dual sound cards, crossover

Tags: audio, usb-audio, pulseaudio-equalizer

So, I'm wanting to setup dual sound cards. I'm thinking I can use paprefs to do simultaneous audio. The question is can I control them separately? I'd like to output 5.1 and 5.1, while 1 card is mids/highs (300hz-20khz) and the other card output the bass (1hz-350hz). Obviously the x.1 will be LFE on both cards so no mids/highs on it.

I'd love to control the crossover via software like this somehow vs. using 1 sound card and 5 linkwitz-riley 2 way crossovers @ $25-$30/each. Also linkwitz-riley would be 1 set frequency, can't change, see what sounds better, etc. Without doing a lot of unsoldering, soldering, buying bunch of different value caps/resistors.

Currently I have 5.1 analog leaving pc, going into amplifier, then to a crossover in speaker. This works, but I think it would be more efficient and sound better if I could get rid of the crossovers on the speaker and have it done before amplifying. Also this would allow me to increase power to the 10" and 12" woofers without increasing power to the 2" and 4" speakers.

I have 3 amplifiers, 8x100watt,8x100watt,1x400watt I would probably interweave the mids/highs and bass to kep amps balanced instead of having all treble one 1 amp and all bass on the other. I'm thinking FL(treble) amp0ch0, FL(bass) amp0ch1, FR(treble) amp1ch0, FR(bass) amp1ch1, etc..

Thoughts?

Comment: I doubt you can do that with `paprefs`. You need LADSPA modules to do the frequency filtering, and then Pulseaudio modules to distribute that to the two cards. Which means `load-module` with the correct parameters. That setup will add a lot of latency, plus two soundcards have independent clocks, and I'd assume drift between clocks in different frequency ranges **will** be audible. So yes, you can do all that, but it will be a pain to set up, and I'd question the wisdom to do it that way. So maybe edit the question and tell us **why** do you want to do it that way, and what the goal is.

Comment: I already have it in OP of why I want to do it that way. If I use software the crossover point is easily adjusted in .asoundrc until I find where I'd like to keep it depending on what sounds the best and I'd only have to buy another sound card.